# Private files broken

Tags: 7, files

I just moved a site to another server (Windows IIS 8.5). Public images are working perfectly, but private images seem to be broken.

By having a look at the browser's inspector, I can see that when I access an image directly, (e.g. http://example.com/?q=system/files/styles/medium/private/my-image.jpg&itok=AtJsTUJ1) I get a 200 status response, however the browser shows the *broken image* icon.

So far, I have tried the following things:

- Set Drupal's default download method to private / public
- Disable / Enable drupal_fast_404() in settings.php
- Changing private folder's permissions

Has anyone experienced something similar or can give a hint on where to look for next?

Comment: Did you try to access the link directly by typing out the path in the location bar? Did you try different browsers?